# Declare a variable which converts Date data type to Integer

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, declare

In SQL Server, the following code gives me the date of Sunday last week from whatever date it is today:

```
DECLARE @dt date = GETDATE();
SELECT dateadd(week,datediff(week,6,@dt),6);
```

I need to declare a variable from the date given and make that variable an integer. I have tried things like:

```
DECLARE @last_sunday INT;
SELECT dateadd(week,datediff(week,6,@dt),6) INTO @last_sunday FROM xxx;
```

But the problem is that I don't understand which table I should write after *FROM*. In my interpretation the line:

```
dateadd(week,datediff(week,6,@dt),6)
```

is some sort of calculation rather than collecting a value from a data table. How can I make last Sunday's date into a variable that is an integer?

Comment: just `declare @last_sunday int = dateadd(...);`. if there is no table, why try to include one??

Comment: sql server doesn't require a `FROM`

Comment: your problem seems to be using `select` when you're not actually selecting from any table. just use `declare @last_sunday int = foo()` or separately declare and then `set @last_sunday = foo()`.

Comment: `SELECT...INTO` doesn't work for variables either. `SELECT...INTO` takes a dataset a creates a table, using the definition of the dataset, and then inserts that data into said new table. You don't `CREATE` a (table type) variable, you `DECLARE` it. It most certainly won't work with a scalar variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something like this:

**Step 1**

```
DECLARE @date DATE = dateadd(week,datediff(week,6,GETDATE()),6)
```

**Step 2**

```
DECLARE @dateInt AS INT = REPLACE(@date, '-', '')
```

In the first step, you are getting the correct date value in a date data type. Given that the date has the hyphens, you are then using the `REPLACE` function in step 2 to remove them and at the same time converting your date to an integer value.

Finally, to make sure that steps 1 and 2 work, you can run the following query:

```
SELECT @dateInt
```

For today, this will get you the following value: **20210530**

Comment: Thank you @Michele La Ferla for giving me a full answer rather than, as in the comments, pointing out that I'm wrong. I know I'm wrong, why else would I be asking a question on stackoverflow? :'D Anyway, this worked exactly as I wanted, thanks a lot! :D

Comment: @chilifan the comments aren't merely pointing out your query was wrong, they also provide explanations *why* it is wrong, and provide alternatives that do work.

Comment: Also note this answer is dependent on local settings, because `@date` is implicitly converted to a string. And not on every machine the implicitly converted value will contain dashes.

Comment: I know the comments also tried to provide solutions, but they all generated more error messages for me. I'm simply upvoting the one that solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

To make life easier, onw could also create a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION LastSunday ()
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN convert(int,dateadd(week,datediff(week,6,getdate()),6))

END
GO
```

After this you can do:

```
select dbo.LastSunday();
```

Which will (now `3th jun 2021`) result in: `44344`

Comment: that's not what he want, because there no literal correlation between the date value and the integer `44344`, in the sense that the integer does not make sense logically.

Comment: There is no correlation between the number `20210530` and the date `2021-05-30`. The first is just a random number, and the second is the data of last Sunday )which is, in fact, a rondom date....

Comment: of course there is a correlation. Visibly it makes much more sense than `44344`

Answer (score 0):

simplest query:

```
select cast(replace(cast(getdate() as date),'-','') as int) as DateToInteger
```